# How to auto-indent code in Coda 2?

Tags: formatting, coda

I just installed Coda 2 but can't find how to auto-format / auto-indent the code.
In Dreamweaver there is this useful function called "Apply Source Formatting" which basically removes white space and auto indents the code, I can't find how to do this in Coda.
The only thing I found is a plugin called "White Out", but it doesn't seem to work.
Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

Select all text or code of your document and press **CMD + Shift + F12**

Comment: This doesn't work.